# psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: column "price" is of type integer but expression is of type text[]

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm working on a project that scrapes zillow from rental listing info (address, price/mo, url) that then stores that info Postgres. I've been getting the error above whenever I run my function that goes to scape and store the info:

```
all_link_elements = soup.select(".list-card-top a")

    all_links = []
    for link in all_link_elements:
        href = link["href"]
        print(href)
        if "http" not in href:
            all_links.append(f"https://www.zillow.com{href}")
        else:
            all_links.append(href)

    all_address_elements = soup.select(".list-card-info address")
    all_addresses = [address.get_text().split(" | ")[-1] for address in all_address_elements]

    all_price_elements = soup.select(".list-card-heading")
    all_prices = []
    for element in all_price_elements:
        #retrieve prices. single/multi lists have different tag/class structures
        try:
            time.sleep(1)
            #price w/ only one listing
            price = element.select(".list-card-price")[0].contents[0].replace('$', '').replace(',', '')\
                .replace('+/mo', '')
            int(price)
        except IndexError:
            #multi
            print("Multiple listings for the card")
            price = element.select(".list-card-details li")[0].contents[0].replace('$', '').replace(',', '')\
                .replace('+/mo', '')
            int(price)
        finally:
            all_prices.append(price)

        for n in range(len(all_links)):
            db.create_search_listing_table()
            sl = SearchListing(address=all_addresses, price=all_prices, url=all_links)
            db.insert_search_listing(sl)
            my_listings = db.get_all_search_listings()
            for listing in my_listings:
                print(f"id: {listing.id} address: {listing.address} price: {listing.price} url {listing.url}")
```

The console then points me to an issue with how I'm trying to insert that info from my database.py.

```
   def insert_search_listing(self, search_listing) -> int:
        logging.debug(
            f"Attempting to insert search listing: {search_listing}")
        self.cur.execute(
            """
            INSERT INTO search_listing (address, price, url)
            VALUES (%(addr)s, %(price)s, %(url)s)
            RETURNING id;
            """,
            {
                "addr": search_listing.address,
                "price": search_listing.price,
                "url": search_listing.url
            }
        )
```

**Edit:** I've tried to do an explicit call with ::int[], and got this error:

`"psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: column "price" is of type integer but expression is of type integer[]"`

I haven't been able to find a clear answer with googling around, so I'm hoping someone might be able to help

Comment: Have you tried `%(price)d`?

Comment: @KlausD. , yes- %d is unsupported. Only %s is supported in python- I'll have to find that source for reference, though

Comment: So what type *is* `search_listing.price`? And what do you expect it to be?

Comment: If I'm following `search_listing.price` is a `list` and from here [Type adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types) a list passed as parameter is adapted to a Postgres `array`(in particular to `text[]`) and it seems the `price` field in the table is defined as an `integer` and hence  the error.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).